# Vagrant with Virtualbox does not start because of standard DHCP "vboxnet0" on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

On `vagrant up` vagrant shows an error starting with:

`A host only network interface you're attempting to configure via DHCP already has a conflicting host only adapter with DHCP enabled. [...]`

This is with a fresh install and a known issue since 2014. The workaround is to execute `VBoxManage dhcpserver remove --netname HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0` manually every time before vagrant up.

But how can this be done automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the following code at the beginning of your Vagrantfile will solve the issue automatically and only execute on linux based os:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      
      host = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
      if host =~ /(linux)/
        config.trigger.before :up do |trigger|
            trigger.warn = "removing standard dhcp host interface if existent"
            trigger.run = {inline: "bash -c 'if [ $( VBoxManage list dhcpservers | grep -c vboxnet0 ) != \"0\" ]; then VBoxManage dhcpserver remove --netname HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0; fi'"}
          end
      end

# [...] your other code here ---

end
```

The code checks if there is a dhcp server whichs name includes the string `vboxnet0` first because otherwise `VBoxManage` would end with an error preventing you from starting up the virtual machine should the standard dhcp not exist (which happens sometimes).